# Line numbers that are not affected by sorting in R DT

Tags: r, dt

Line numbers are displayed by default in R DT packages.

```
dt <- DT::datatable(iris)
dt
```

However, this line number will change according to the record by sorting. This is the correct move.
But I need line numbers that are unaffected by sorting. Is it possible to do this with the R DT package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a loot of time to figure out why the documentation on the Index table didn't work on R but it turns out they were using a shorthand for table as t., here is a working example based on https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

Changed the JS part to allow for exportation as csv

```
 library(DT)
dt <- DT::datatable(iris,options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(searchable= FALSE,
                         orderable =FALSE,
                         targets= 0)),
  order = list(1,"asc")),
  callback   = JS("
  table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
     table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
           cell.innerHTML = i+1;
           table.cell(cell).invalidate('dom');
     });
}).draw();
                  "))
dt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(DT)

datatable(iris, 
          callback = JS(
            "table.on('order.dt search.dt', function(){",
            "  table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes()",
            "    .each(function(cell, i){",
            "      cell.innerHTML = i+1;",
            "    });",
            "}).draw();")
)
```